# why java8 streams consumer andThen method?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am new to Java 8, just want to ask what is the difference in performance between the two code snippets below.

I know both work, but I am wondering why the Java team created [`Consumer::andThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html#andThen-java.util.function.Consumer-) method when I can use the normal approach.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("aaa","cccc","bbbb");
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

**//Approach 1**

```
list.stream().forEach(x -> {
            list2.add(x);
            System.out.println(x);
        });
```

**//Approach 2**

```
Consumer<String> c1 = s -> list2.add(s);
Consumer<String> c2 = s -> System.out.println(s);

list.stream().forEach(c1.andThen(c2));
```

IMO, **approach1** is better, why **approach2** again? If both are same, then why **andThen()** method is created? I guess there must be reason they've created.

In other words, when exactly is the `andThen()` method really helpful?

Comment: I don't think `stream()` is required if you are using `forEach()`. You can directly use `list.forEach()`.

Comment: `andThen` has nothing to do with the Stream API. It's just a feature on the `Consumer` interface (which happens to be the parameter type of `forEach`).

Comment: @ernest_k So, in what scenario andThen() method really helpful/useful?

Comment: Even if I've to add 10 lines of code, I can write them all 10 lines of logic 
 as x -> {// add all 10 lines here}, instead of creating 10 Consumer instances, what you say?

Comment: @john I think you already gave one scenario here, and Eran gives a good answer

Comment: Use code where you need it, I find both approach can be done by just `list.addAll(list2)`

Comment: I would use neither for what you are trying to do in the examples: an enhanced for loop would suffice. In general, it's more powerful (you can assign variables from the outer scope, return, break, throw checked exceptions etc), lighter-weight at runtime. Just because you *can* use functional programming here doesn't mean it's the best choice.

Comment: @AndyTurner In my example above, there are no intermediate operations, but if those exists, then using enhanced for loop is not a good approach, right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I agree that is makes less sense to create a separate `Consumer<String>` instance for each statement just for the sake of using `andThen`.

However, if you already have two `Consumer<String>` instances (`c1` and `c2`), and you need to execute both, you could either write:

```
list.forEach(x -> {
        c1.accept(x);
        c2.accept(x);
    });
```

or

```
list.forEach(c1.andThen(c2));
```

In this case, the latter is clearly cleaner.

EDIT:

I'd like to expand on the case when you create your own `Consumer`s (i.e. not re-using pre-existing ones). When you assign a lambda expression to a `Consumer` variable, you can use that `Consumer` instance in multiple places instead of duplicating the lambda expression. That is true for any functional interface.

Once you decide to use a `Consumer` variable, the decision of whether to have a single `Consumer` implementing complex logic or 2 simpler `Consumer`s, each implementing part of the logic, depends on whether there is a need to be able to execute just part of the logic in some cases (or changing the order in which parts of the logic are executed).

Having `c1` and `c2` allows you either of the following options:

```
list.forEach(c1);
list.forEach(c2);
list.forEach(c1.andThen(c2));
list.forEach(c2.andThen(c1));
```

If you had a single consumer that does the logic of both `c1` and `c2`, you have less flexibility.

Comment: Is `stream()` required here? I think we can omit this.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz that's true

Comment: Also to add to this, the Consumers could be a lot more complex than simply adding or printing values as such. could be modifying / manipulating the data in each item. Imagine reading a source data one by one, and applying transformations that need to be consistent. This makes it much more readable, one consumer manipulates one part, maybe enhances the object then passes on to next, etc, creating a pipeline like setup.

Comment: @Eran so, we can avoid using andThen() method, right? (assume if I don't have c1 and c2 instances already exists)

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz why stream() not required above?

Comment: @john `List` already has a `forEach()` method, so there's no need to create a `Stream`.

Comment: @john In your simple example, it makes no sense to pre-define the two `Consumer`s just for the sake of using `andThen`, so yes, I would avoid using it.

Comment: @Eran I think we need to append forEach() only for parallelStream() method, right?

Comment: @Eran Above example is just 2 lines of code, BUT what if I have 10 lines of logic, so in this case, do you create 10 Consumer instances and use andThen()?

Comment: @john You can use `forEach()` with `stream()` too, if you're using other intermediate operations like `map()`, `filter()` etc. And yes if you want to execute in parallel then you can use it with `parallelStream()`.

Comment: Suppose you want to print values that match a certain condition then you can do this: `list.stream().filter(x -> x.startsWith("a")).forEach()`. Now it makes sense to use `stream()`.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz okay, thnq!

Comment: @Eran Above example is just 2 lines of code, BUT what if I have 10 lines of logic, so in this case, do you create 10 Consumer instances and use andThen()?

Comment: @john it depends. lambda expressions with curly braces make the code less tidy in my opinion. If you have a `Consumer` with complex logic (many statements), you should consider putting that logic in a method, and using a method reference. Splitting the `Consumer`s makes sense if they have reason to exist on their own - for example, if in some cases you use only `c1`, in other cases you use only `c2` and sometimes you combine both.

Answer (score 3):

Just as a side note, there is another approach possible:

**Approach 3**

```
list.stream()
        .peek(System.out::println)
        .forEach(list2::add);
```

or even better:

```
List<String> list2 = list.stream()
        .peek(System.out::println)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Performance-wise all the approaches are comparable, but the last one is the most "functional". The problem with the previous ones is the insertion into the second list inside the stream. This is a side-effect, which is considered a bad practice. From this perspective, the approach with the two consumers is the worst in my opinion, since the side effect is the most hidden.

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions in the original post:

- is it better regarding performance?
- why introducing Consumer and other functional interface?

Performance-wise, I don't think it would be better; considering the time classic foreach loop have existed, optimisation of memory usage and other aspects may long have been there; and the overhead of creating other references in Consumer, so no, it's not faster/lighter.

So why? It's not about if it's faster, but about a **paradigm shift**, marking one new phase of Java when you can start thinking from the functional way. Before, functional perspective/way of programming or thinking in Java is not natively supported, but now it is. A "pipeline stream" way of processing data now is syntactically possible and readable. So it's an effort to achieve syntax and semantics consistency, so you can write in functional way, and others can understand because it can be read in a fluent way, with proper keyword assembling corresponding meaning. To know that **how you read affects how you think**, and if you cannot write/read it in a functional way, you cannot think so in Java. So it's a step towards making Java a multi-paradigm language.

(Apache Camel does pipeline processing in its concept even before that, even without this; but that's a rare example in a language like Java where functional was not there from the beginning).

Imagine now you can write code:

```
// functional and easy to read
readInput().forEach(convertToUpperCase().andThen().store());
```

vs.

```
// faster but not functional
readInput().forEach(word -> {
    String upperCase = convertToUpperCase();
    store(upperCase);
}
```

That's just one simple example so the difference is small; but I imagine there could be code much easier to read in functional way and you could understand the whole process just by reading it, vs. traditional Java non-functional way where it's obfuscate to understand what is happening without fully diving into code across several places.

Not knowing much about functional programming but the style is simple and beautiful even with my current shallow experience: one element being transformed/joined with others/grouped, among other processing, then result.

Answer (score -1):

The most obvious use case seems to the ability to combine your consumers as you wish while making each one of them re-usable. It does just make the code cleaner and more "functional ready".
It will not be much useful if you don't need to re-use the same consumer logic elsewhere.